# How to pause real time in Perl

Tags: perl

I am quite new to Perl and this is my first post here so be gentle.

I am using real time in a countdown timer of 60 seconds and need to be able to stop it every 10 seconds and the user must then input whether they would like to continue the countdown or not at each interval of 10. The timer works, I just can't figure out how to pause it for the user to input their response. As basic of an answer as possible would be very welcomed as I do not understand a lot yet. Thank you and here is my code so far.

```
my $countdown = 1*60; #60 seconds
$| = 1; #disable output buffering

my $start_time = time;
my $end_time = $start_time + $countdown;


for (;;) {
    my $time = time;
    last if ($time >= $end_time);
    printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d",
        ($end_time - $time) / (1*60),
        ($end_time - $time) / 60%60,
        ($end_time - $time) % 60,
    );

    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: `$input = <>;` will wait for input from the user.

Comment: Use a 10s timer in a loop executed 6 times.

Comment: Decrement `$countdown` each time through the loop. After the user answers the prompt, recalculate `$end_time` using the current time and value of `$countdown`.

Comment: do you want the timer to pause when you wait for user input, or not?

Comment: I wish I could pause real time with Perl. It would be most convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `$end_time` after getting the response from the user.

```
while (1) {
    $countdown--;
    $time = time;
    last if ($time >= $end_time);
    printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d",
        ($end_time - $time) / (1*60),
        ($end_time - $time) / 60%60,
        ($end_time - $time) % 60,
    );

    sleep(1);
    if ($countdown%10 == 0) {
        print "Continue? ";
        $answer = <>;
        chomp $answer;
        last if $answer ne 'y';
        $end_time = time + $countdown;
    }
}
```

Comment: That might block the program, but that doesn't pause the timer.

Comment: There's no timer in his code, he's just counting down and sleeping 1 second between each iteration.

Comment: If you take 10 seconds to answer, the program will run for 60 seconds. If you take 20 seconds to answer, the program will run for 60 seconds. That doesn't pause the timer, except if you take longer than 10 secs to answer the last question.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the help! I tried both codes but Barmar's code worked a little better for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use a 10s countdown in a loop executed 6 times.

```
for my $i (1..6) {
    if ($i != 1) {
        print "\nContinue? ";
        $answer = <>;
        chomp $answer;
        last if !( $answer eq 'y' || $answer eq 'yes' );
    }

    countdown(10);
}
```

Where `countdown` is simply the code you posted.

```
sub countdown {
    my ($length) = @_;

    my $start_time = time;
    my $end_time = $start_time + $length;
    for (;;) {
        my $time = time;
        last if $time >= $end_time;
        printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d",
            ($end_time - $time) / (1*60),
            ($end_time - $time) / 60%60,
            ($end_time - $time) % 60,
        );

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```