# Have a countdown timer stop at certain times and ask for input

Tags: perl, loops, countdown

A project I am doing for class wants me to have a counter start at 60 and count down (printing each number as it goes), but the counter needs to stop at 10 second intervals and ask for user input. I have that part of the program working in the form of a "password". Where I am running into issues is having my sub routines work together to get what I want it to do. Here is what I have so far.

```perl
print "Enter password: ";
my $password = <STDIN>;
chomp($password);

if ( $password eq "password" ) {
    &counter;
} else {
    print "bad";
}

sub counter {
    our $countdown = 60;

    while ( $countdown > 0 ) {
        $countdown--;
        &check;
        print "$countdown\n";
    }
}

sub check {
    if ( our $countdown = ( 50, 40, 30, 20, 10 ) ) {
        print "Enter password: ";
        my $password = <STDIN>;
        chomp($password);
    }
    if ( $password eq "password" ) {
        &counter;
    } else {
        print "bad";
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732221/how-to-pause-real-time-in-perl

Answer (score 1):

PythonMaster's answer is okay except it ignores that this was a *Perl* question.

```
$|++;  # unbuffered output
my $counter = 60;
my $passed;
while ($counter) {
    $counter--;
    print "$counter...\cm";
    if ( not $counter % 10 ) {
        last if $passed = check();
    }
    sleep 1;
}
print "\n";
print "All password attempts failed!\n" unless $passed;

sub check {
    print "\nEnter password: ";
    my $password = <STDIN>;
    chomp($password);
    return  $password eq "password";
}
```

Notes:

- `$|` unbuffers the standard output if it's a non-zero value. Since we want to see the countdown output as it comes out, we need to unbuffer STDOUT.
- The key bit is using the modulus operator to decide when we're at a multiple of 10 (the modulus is zero when that's true; since zero is a 'false' value in Perl, we `not` that to get an expression that is true when the modulus is zero.
- `check()` is simplified to simply return the result of the comparison. If it's true, then the function returns a true value, and returns false otherwise.
- `last if $passed = check()` does triple duty: if checks the password, it saves the value, and it ends the loop if the password is OK.
- The extra `"\n"` characters are used to both drop the password prompt to the next line, and ensure that the final "failed" message appears on its own line.
- the `"\cm"` makes the countdown stay on the same line until the password prompt occurs.

*Edit:* the solution linked to in the comment above is *much* better than this one.